# Drive usage issue / Linux

Tags: disk-usage

I'm new in linux, Today I've logged in to my server and found that my 2TB drive is 95% full, which sounds incredible, and all services are down, the only access I have right now is SSH, I did try to find where are this files using `df -H`  it show me in: /dev/vda1 , but going trough all folders will take ages.

how can I find easily where are the files and what causes the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
du -msh /*
```

it will shows which directory, then follow the biggest size, for instance:

```
du -msh /var/*
```

then

```
du -msh /var/www/*
```

so on..

The reason can be anything, from upload of some files by users if you have them to log files caused by some error etc.